# Alpha-blended splash screen renders garbage in XP but works in Win7

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I have a borderless form which has the following code:

```
public partial class Splash : Form
{
    bool painted = false;

    public Splash()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Opacity = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (painted)
            return;

        Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(new Point(Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top),
                           Point.Empty, Bounds.Size);
        gfx.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Splash, e.ClipRectangle);

        Opacity = 100;
        painted = true;
    }
}
```

This works quite well on my Windows 7 machine, but in Windows XP it shows garbage (presumably whatever misaligned stuff is in the framebuffer) instead of the splash image. I can sometimes make out highly distorted remnants of old explorer windows, etc inside the garbage.

Strange thing is, I run identical code in a different program which has the same sort of 24-bit PNG and that works fine on the XP machine.

Any idea why this might be happening?

---

**Solution:**

Add `Bitmap b;` after the `bool painted = false;` line, and change the `OnPaintBackground` to:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!painted)
    {
        b = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);

        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(Bounds.Left, Bounds.Top),
                         Point.Empty, Bounds.Size);
        g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Splash, e.ClipRectangle);

        Opacity = 100;
        painted = true;

        g.Dispose();
    }

    Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
    gfx.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0));
    gfx.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but try commenting out the "if (painted) return;" line

Comment: @MerickOWA If I comment out that line, then it will `CopyFromScreen` over and over, and the alpha blending will disappear entirely from all the layers.

Comment: Don't forget to call g.Dispose() when you are done with the graphics object inside the If block.  Otherwise you will leak a graphics handle.  Probably not a huge problem in this case, since it only happens once, but it's a good habit to get in to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you not refreshing the form after you painted him once. Win XP stores not any graphic content of windows, he just notifies them to paint themselves. Your `OnPaint` and `OnPaintBackground` functions should always refresh the window.
I do not understand why you don't use the `BackgroundImage` property, along with `Opacity`. You can set the image to be stretched, zoomed, etc. Did you want to show an effect?

Comment: I re-wrote the OnPaintBackground so that the first time it runs, it does the `CopyFromScreen` and stores it in a `Bitmap`. Subsequent paints just redraw the image. This appears to work, but I'm very confused why this exact code works fine with my other program on the same computer but had this problem with this program.

Comment: @Ozzah I think you're just lucky.  This message is sent multiple times and must be painted whenever the OS asks.  There's alot of things that can cause this to happen like what other programs are running in the background or differences in how the OS works.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a form with .BorderStyle set to None with a .TransparencyKey set?  It should mimic the effect you are trying to get without the hassle of the CopyFromScreen call.

**edited based on comments**

I found some example source code that does the per pixel alpha blending you want, but it is far more complex and involves pInvoke.  For reference you can find it here. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx

Comment: As I said, I'm already using a borderless form. TransparencyKey doesn't support full alpha-blending. I have a partially transparent splash with a 24-bit PNG. Like I said, the exact above code works on XP with my previous program but not this one.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense.  If I recall there is another method of window composting that supports an alpha mask, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: I found the code I was looking for, but its actually far more complex than the code you are using.  If you are still interested, the source code for an example can be found here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/perpxalpha_sharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that Win7 stores graphic content of windows and redraws them automatically. You can see the difference when a window is not responding- in WinXP he will not be refreshed, and in Win7 he will look OK. And also the window preview when you hover over the taskbar, and the "form growing" effect when a form appears.
I writing this in a seperated answer because i don't know how to add a comment in this site...